# sed to remove from a character to a character

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have certain data like following.

```
<some-thing>my-data<some-thing>
```

I would like to search a character '<' and remove till '>' and need a output like following.

```
my-data
```

Is there a way to do it with sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/<.*?>//g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is no < and > in your data

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g
```

if < or > could appear in the data content

```
sed 's/^<[^>]*>\(.*\)<[^>]*>$/\1/'
```

assuming that any line having tag < > are in the case.

remark: Often tag start with a `<tag>` and stop with a `</tag>`

Comment: you have a bunch of errors: missing `/` in the first command, missing `*` in both commands.

Comment: right, post occur before the end of reply with a VI edit habit :-( post is OK now, thanks for info

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do it:

```
echo "<some-thing>my-data<some-thing>" | awk '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/, " ");$1=$1}1'
my-data
```